# How can I change Unity's super-t binding to something else?

Tags: unity, trash, shortcut-keys

First, I've tried searching several threads to find the answer, but I couldn't find one that solved my problem, so I'm opening a new one here.

I just installed Ubuntu 11.04 with the new Unity desktop, and I'm trying to change the key binding of <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> from Open Trash (which I don't have much use for) to Open Terminal (which I use all the time).  I tried running "Keyboard shortcuts" and changing the binding in there to "Mod t," but that didn't work and it seems to get overridden by something else.

So then I installed `compiz-config-settings-manager` and I looked for a keybinding in there for <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>, but I couldn't find any.  In fact, I even tried changing a random feature in ccsm to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> hoping that it would tell me there was a conflict with that binding and I could locate it there.  But instead it let me use <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>. Sadly, after I changed it, I pressed <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and it still opened the trash.

Is there another place that I can change the key bindings of <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>?

Comment: It might not help, but by default in Unity you can open the Terminal by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T.

Comment: Yes, a real answer is necessary here. Why does the tool designed for keybinding manipulation get overridden by unity defaults?

Comment: It seems that the issue is that it's hard-coded into unity.
Big failure, I think

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the Compiz Config open the Unity Plugin page, change the "Key to show the launcher" to anything other than just <kbd>Super</kbd>. Mine is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>.

This will alter all Unity shortcuts. 
So opening the first program in your launcher is no longer <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> but <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>.

They should really have a configuration panel for Unity shortcuts.

Comment: @aldomann, thanks for the comment.  I prefer Super+t over Ctrl+Alt+t, but it's working for now

Comment: thanks for the response.  I agree, they should have a configuration panel.  Til then, I'll have to evaluate giving up other features of Unity's using only the Super key for my terminal shortcut.

Comment: @Eufouria, I also changed the Unity launcher key to Alt+Super but Alt+Super+1 does not launch the first program as expected.
It only works when the launcher key is set to Super.
Does it work for you? I suspect it's a bug. I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 x64.

Comment: I had to change settings on Unity Plugin page several times before they took place. The settings kept resetting without no apparent reason. I also sensed different behaviour when using Unity or Unity 2D.

Answer (score 4):

This **isn't** a real answer to the question but another approach in unity manner.

If you use it often consider putting it into the unity launcher. Just search for "terminal" and then drag the icon to the left side pane. You can then start it with <kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>[number]</kbd>.

Just in case you're interested: I want to know the real answer too!

Comment: I thought this was useful, because it was a common-sense answer to the question, given that the actual answer is "unsolvable issue".

Comment: I do this too. Lets me open terminal quickly with just my left hand. I assume that is what you were going for.

Answer (score 3):

My muscle memory is also programmed to use <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> for open terminal, so I decided to make a ppa for this: https://launchpad.net/~hansvschoot/+archive/ubuntu/unity7.
It contains the unity 7.2 branch at the moment (which is used in 14.04) with line 56 of the launcher/TrashLauncherIcon.cpp commented out to remove the shortcut.

So if you are running ubuntu 14.04 you can run the following commands to add the ppa and install the modified unity:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:hansvschoot/unity7
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity
```

afterwards you can simply use the shortcuts tab under keyboard settings to assign <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> to open a terminal

Comment: Sorry, but I've installed your plugin but it doesn't seem to work. Have you got any idea why?

Comment: This is a pretty bad idea.  Making a custom PPA for Unity will likely end up with many people having outdated versions of unity running on their system.

Answer (score -1):

The default shortcut for opening a terminal is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, so you don't necessarily need to change it, just start using the default.

But if you do want to customize shortcuts, the keyboard settings panel in Ubuntu 13.10 (I will confirm 14.04 soon), is where the "Launch terminal" shortcut is controlled.

I changed it to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and it now works to open a terminal instead of the trash.

Comment: Nah, I doesn't work in 14.04.

Comment: Also confirmed it no longer works in 15.04.

Comment: not work in 16.04 either