# Change super+t to open a terminal

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys

I'd like to change the <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> that opens the trash to open the terminal, as i see the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> un-needed because i hardly use the trash as much as i use the bash

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I change unity's super-t binding to open the trash?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/35688/how-can-i-change-unitys-super-t-binding-to-open-the-trash)

Answer (score 3):

For that you will have to disable the <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> shortcut in compiz settings in the unity section then change the terminal shortcut in keyboard shortcuts to <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

Comment: There is no such option as disabling the super+T in CompizConfig Settings Manager > Ubuntu Unity Plugin. This is the case at least with my freshly installed 12.04 32-bit.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't an option to deselect super+T in the unity settings in Compiz.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this would break some dependencies, but try this:

1. Assign to unity launcher 'Ctrl+T' shortcut
2. Assign back your desired key shortcut unity launcher.
3. Now you can try to assign 'Ctrl+T' shortcut to terminal and etc.

Worked on 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 22.04 I did it by going to **Settings -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> Launchers -> Launch Terminal**.

There I assigned it to **Super + T**.

[image]

[Change super+t to open a terminal. Ubuntu Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elDPL.jpg)