# Bind Super + Numpad 4

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 and would like to rebind <kbd>Super + Num4</kbd> to "Put window on the left side of the screen"

Based upon [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116744/restore-the-ctrl-alt-num-pad-4-and-6-window-positioning-commands), I was able to setup my binding using the CompizConf Grid settings, however the default hotkey to for the 4th Launcher icon is taking precedence over my binding. How can I remove default Ubiquity hotkeys so that they do not interfere with my own?

Comment: Looks like the answer is here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/35688/how-can-i-change-unitys-super-t-binding-to-something-else

This is quite the hodgepodge of searching required to figure out how to do this. Perhaps making a community wiki explaining how to override the Super key in Ubiquity would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the answer is here: [How can I change Unity's super-t binding to something else?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35688/how-can-i-change-unitys-super-t-binding-to-something-else)

> In the Compiz Config open the Unity Plugin page, change the "Key to show the launcher" to anything other than just "< Super>". Mine is < Alt>< Super>

This is quite the hodgepodge of searching required to figure out how to do this. Perhaps making a community wiki explaining how to override the Super key in Ubiquity would be nice.