# Minimize all shortcut Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, shortcuts, minimize

I don't usually ask questions but I can't find a working solution anywhere.

I went to *Settings > keyboard > shortcuts > Navigation > Hide all normal windows* and changed the shortcut to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to match windows minimize all shortcut. However <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> opens music search (that I certainly don't need).

How can I remove the this music search binding?

`gsettings`/`dconf` location would certainly help, but couldn't find it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this in another thread. 
What I needed to do is to rewire Unity launch button as a whole.

> in the Compiz Config open the Unity Plugin page, change the "Key to show the launcher" to anything other than just Super. Mine is Alt+Super.
>   [original thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35688/how-can-i-change-unitys-super-t-binding-to-something-else)

Afterwards all started to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal by pressing CTRL+ALT+T

Enter the command below.

```
sudo apt-get remove unity-lens-music
```

Enter the root password when prompted.

Now goto **Settings > keyboard > shortcuts > Navigation > Hide all normal windows** and assign the Super+M keys

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. Ive already done it before and was surprised to see that this didnt do the trick.                                                                            root@RUDOV5L:~# sudo apt-get remove unity-lens-music
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'unity-lens-music' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.

Comment: Then try this one. sudo apt-get purge unity-lens-music

Comment: its not installed so it was not removed. ive also done autoremove (if that was the next step). I have a feeling that its not called "unity-lens-music"